# Alternative to Support Vector Machine for Intent Classification

Tags: nlp, svm, chatbot, text-classification

I am trying to implement a chatbot using linked data. In a paper, I read that I can use SVM for the intent classification which is basically the first stage in conversational systems. It is the process of mapping queries to a predefined class. I wanted to know whether there is any other way or applications / programs that I can use to do this. Could someone please advise me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Rasa](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/) is an open-source platform that can be used to easily set up a chatbot, and through it you can set up several kinds of intent classification (including [with an SVM](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/next/components#sklearnintentclassifier)).

It also allows you to [annotate example utterances](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/user-guide/annotate-nlu-examples) and map them to intents within the tool itself.

These tasks are certainly doable on your own, but if speed and easy integration with a working chatbot are priorities, then I recommend using a platform like that.